# Using both annotation and XML config on one instance bean

Tags: java, spring

I'm creating a service using annotation:

```
@Service
@Repository
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
  private String defaultPassword;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  // ...

  @Override
  public void setDefaultPassword(String defaultPassword) {
     this.defaultPassword = defaultPassword;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDefaultPassword() {
     return defaultPassword;
  }
}
```

I want to configure `defaultPassword` value using Spring XML configuration not via annotation, so I added the following in XML definition:

```
<bean id="userServiceImpl" class="com.test.service.UserServiceImpl">
   <property name="defaultPassword" value="youmustchangethis" />
</bean>
```

Then, I write test like:

```
public class UserServiceImplTest extends AbstractServiceImplTest {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  // ...
}
```

I've matched the bean name in annotation and XML declaration (using bean id). My question is will `userService` variable in `UserServiceImplTest` always injected by the same singleton bean that configured in both XML and annotation?  I've searched the documentation but didn't find explanation for 'hybrid' approach like this.

Comment: remove `@Repository` annotation, you should use one of `stereotype` annotation

Comment: I want to use Spring unchecked exception here because I injected Spring Data repository in my service layer. If I must removed `@Repository` annotation, is there another way to use Spring unchecked exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case bean defined in xml file will overwrite bean generated from annotation. That is because spring names annotation beans based on the class name with the first letter changed into lowercase. Unless you give it an explit name. There cannot exist two beans of the same name so xml definition overrides the annotation one.

You end up with one singleton called `userServiceImpl` here.

Comment: Thank for the answer. If XML definition overrides the annotation one, will that mean I lost all annotation feature such as unchecked exception support defined by `@Repository` or transactional support if I use `@Transactional`?

Comment: No, all annotations are still there and they are supported properly. The only difference is you end up with one bean definition instead of two. The xml bean has everything annotation bean had plus `defaultPassword`.